# Can't change JavaScript Code Style in PhpStorm settings

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I'm working on a react-native project. I want to enable the Code Style to add spaces within ES6 import/export brackets.

However, the `OK`, `CANCEL` and `APPLY` buttons on the bottom right do not appear inside the JavaScript code style window. If I got to HTML or certain other languages settings I can see them. Changes do not persist when I make changes.

So, short story even shorter. I can't actually change my code style for JavaScript and save it. Anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: It looks unusually large as for me ... 1) Can you disable Material Theme UI plugin, restart IDE and see if it will make any difference 2) If you resize the Settings screen -- will section with the controls appear again? P.S. In any case --  try setting your desired options here and swithcing to another setting page where controls are visible -- this should work as a possible workaround.

Comment: Wow that worked, switching to HTML and clicking save. Thank you! Also resizing the window worked :) Feel free to answer and I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest to disable Material Theme UI plugin and restart IDE. This plugin modifies GUI bits quite a bit and sometimes causes random issues in different areas that otherwise are not present.

I'm not saying "disable it permanently" but to at very least just to check and confirm if this will make any difference.

---

In any case, possible workarounds are:

1. Try resizing the actual Settings window (bottom right corner) -- making it larger should make the section with controls to become visible again.
2. Try setting your desired options for JavaScript and then switch to another settings page (e.g. HTML or just Code Style) where those controls are visible already.

   "Apply" / "OK" buttons affect all Settings and not just currently visible settings page.